# Measure to calculate Running sum of n rows for each group in PowerBI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this data with Group and Values. I want to sum "Values" on a rolling window of 4 rows sorted by "Date" as shown in the "Result". I want this calculation separately for each "Group".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple running sum:

```
RunningSum = 

var currRow = SELECTEDVALUE('ValByGroup'[Date])
return
CALCULATE( sum('ValByGroup'[Value]), filter(ALLEXCEPT('ValByGroup', 'ValByGroup'[Group]),  'ValByGroup'[Date] <= currRow && 'ValByGroup'[Date] > currRow-4 ))
```

[image]

EDIT:

we can add additional Index Column to our table.
Here example.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtI1MAQiJR2lRCA2UIrVwSJsiCpshF3YBLshpthVg8xOwm42FmET7MKm2IWNEcKxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Group = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Group", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Group"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, Group=nullable text, Value=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"index",1)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Date", "Group", "Value", "index"}, {"Custom.Date", "Custom.Group", "Custom.Value", "Custom.index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Count", "Group"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.Date", "Date"}, {"Custom.Group", "Group"}, {"Custom.Value", "Value"}, {"Custom.index", "index"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Then instead of [Date] we can use IndexColumn in our measure

Comment: This solution fails to include cases when the dates are not consecutive or if there are missing dates between rows. Can you please suggest a work around?

Comment: Check my update. Add an index column to your table.